# Django не загружает static файлы

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Работаю в PyCharm.
В index.html у меня прописано:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>22</title>
        {% load static %}
        <script src="{% static  "mapping/js/map.js"%}"></script>
        <style src="{% static  "mapping/css/styles.css"%}"></style>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1> Hello world </h1>
    </body>
```

А в папке изменен цвет на синий static/mapping/css/styles.css

```
h1 {
  color: #5b80b2;
}
```

браузер выдает вот это
[image: issue]

Comment: А где и как вы используете этот index.html?

Comment: в settings.py подключен INSTALLED_APPS = [ django.contrib.staticfiles ]  и STATIC_URL = '/static/'?

Comment: Статические файлы тут ни при чем. Чтоб теги работали (`{% ... %}`), нужно чтоб index.html обработал движок шаблонов django. Если вы просто обращаетесь к index.html, как к статическому файлу, то вы увидите необработанное содержимое. Читайте https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/

Comment: @andreymal index.html находится в папке templates в приложении Mapping. Mapping/templates/map/index.html А папка static в Mapping/static/mapping/css/styles.css

Comment: @Alexandr Да, работаю в PyCharm, там эти конфигурации уже автоматически введены

Comment: @RomanKonoval Какой командой он обрабатывает движок? Не могу найти.. в index прописал load static чтобы он загрузил файл static, но он просто дублирует его на страницу

Comment: Я дал выше ссылку, где описано как пользоваться шаблонами. Еще раз повторюсь, если вы используете html как статический файл, то его содержимое передается на клиент, и теги никто не обработает и они так и останутся на странице, что вы и наблюдаете. Чтоб теги заменились, нужно чтоб шаблон html файла обработал движок шаблонов django. Тут в двух словах не описать, как его использовать, смотрите доку, что я дал выше.

Comment: Вот ответ с примером, как сделать так, чтоб шаблон обработался https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151875/2231972

Comment: @RomanKonoval Тоесть в идеале, мне надо написать код в models или views, чтобы в дальнейшем html был более интерактивным? В данный момент в views.py у меня ```` def mapping(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "map/index.html") ```` Может ли быть проблема в этом?

Comment: @RomanKonoval ВОт я следовал этому туториалу https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial06/

Comment: Охх, у меня получилось решить проблему благодаря этому сайту https://www.javatpoint.com/django-static-files-handling  Но я так понимаю что сервер  http://127.0.0.1:8000/map/ и html будут всегда отличаться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение на вопрос нашел здесь, переходя через серверную строку все работает как надо. https://www.javatpoint.com/django-static-files-handling